# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *=

Tags: python, typeerror, python-3.3, operand

I'm teaching myself Python via an online wikibook, and came across a confusing error in one of the examples with overloading operators. According to the example:

```
class FakeNumber:
    n = 5
    def __add__(A,B):
        return A.n + B.n

c = FakeNumber()
d = FakeNumber()
d.n = 7

c.__imul__ = lambda B: B.n - 6
c *= d
c
```

is supposed to return:
`1`
but instead I get:
`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *=: 'FakeNumber' and 'FakeNumber'`

I get that you can't multiply objects together, so then what is the point of `c.__imul__ = lambda B: B.n - 6`? Is there something missing, or where is there improper syntax?

Reference: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Classes#Operator_Overloading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed the code is working as intended in python 2, but not in 3. A possible fix in python 3 would be the following:

```
class FakeNumber:
    def __init__(self, i):
        self.i = i

    def __imul__(self, B):
        self.i = self.i * B.i
        return self

a = FakeNumber(5)
b = FakeNumber(6)

a *= b
```

Comment: So if I'm following along correctly, when a FakeNumber object is constructed, it expects to be passed in a variable. Where is it storing that variable?

Answer (score 0):

The link explains Python 2 and you're trying it on Python 3.  The difference can be explained in detail (look for "old-style classes" versus "new-style classes" if you want to know), but it resumes to: special methods like `__imul__` are now always ignored if they are defined on an *instance*.  They are only called if they are defined on the *class* of the instance.  So the line

```
c.__imul__ = lambda B: B.n - 6
```

does not have the intended effect of defining the behavior of the `+=` operator: `c` is just an instance of the class `C`.

Comment: @Armin_Rigo I'm not very good with lambda; what would I write to fix this?

Comment: See the answer by @Teisman, and generally don't use lambdas.  I've no clue why they use lambdas in teaching material, actually.